# Exporting kernel utilization distributions from R to be used in ArcGIS Pro scene view

Tags: r, arcgis-pro, georeferencing, r-bridge

I have used the "kde" function "ks" package to estimate 95% kernel utilization distributions (KUD) to visualize the 3D activity range of an arboreal snake.

Below is code that I modified from Simpfendorfer et al (2012) to accomplish this:

> Simpfendorfer, C. A., E. M. Olsen, M. R. Heupel, and E. Moland. 2012.
>   Three-dimensional kernel utilization distributions improve estimates
>   of space use in aquatic animals. Canadian Journal of Fisheries and
>   Aquatic Sciences 69:565-572.

I generated KUDs in R and I can visualize them within the RGL environment. However, I would like to export KUDs so that I can import them into ArcGIS Pro and create 3D images in a scene view.

How do I accomplish this, perhaps using R-ArcGIS bridge?

R Script:

```
install.packages("ks")
install.packages("MASS")
install.packages("KernSmooth")

#Loads necessary libraries
library("ks")
library("MASS")
library("KernSmooth")

#Reads files for Animal A into R workspace, where ''Animal a.csv'' 
#is a file with X,Y,Z coordinates

a<-read.csv("Scott/R data/Snake3.csv")

#Runs the kernel density analysis
fhata<-kde(x=a, H=BandA, binned=FALSE, xmin=c(minX,minY,minZ), xmax=c(maxX,maxY,maxZ), gridsize = 250)

#Produce a 3D plot
plot(fhata,cont=95, bty='n', colors="red", drawpoints=FALSE, axes=FALSE, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", zlab="Meters", xlab="Easting", ylab="Northing", zlim=c(-1,6))
```

Example data set:

```
(Snake3; X=Easting, Y=Northing, Z=Height): 
X   Y   Z
269010.1657 1504460.332 -1
269004.0495 1504503.546 0
268999.6519 1504495.838 -1
269004.001  1504498.013 -1
268997.5064 1504498.07  -1
268997.6713 1504516.882 -1
269009.5489 1504513.458 -1
269003.1223 1504521.261 -1
269003.1029 1504519.048 -1
269000.3075 1504447.138 -1
268956.3938 1504500.644 -1
268978.6825 1504573.49  -1
269019.8008 1504448.074 -1
269019.345  1504396.063 0
268978.5717 1504437.368 0
269044.4541 1504420.19  0
268959.8448 1504523.854 -1
269006.7438 1504440.441 0.5
269000.7925 1504502.468 -1
269031.9    1504466.4   0.5
268994.9051 1504448.292 3.5
269007.2773 1504501.304 0
269002.9282 1504499.129 -1
269013.6555 1504487.968 -1
269016.9512 1504493.473 -1
269010.5052 1504499.063 -1
269010.4373 1504491.317 -1
269009.3646 1504492.433 -1
269031.9209 1504472.315 2
269026.4215 1504462.403 2
269022.1597 1504470.187 2
269019.9657 1504466.886 2
269016.7475 1504470.234 3.5
269016.6214 1504455.848 1.5
268984.1681 1504458.346 0.25
268966.4558 1504537.076 -1
268988.0169 1504526.927 0
268999.9041 1504524.609 3
269006.7923 1504445.974 3
269016.5438 1504446.996 -1
269019.9657 1504466.886 1.8
269013.8107 1504505.674 3.7
268953.4861 1504539.403 -1
268966.3005 1504519.371 3
268972.8533 1504525.953 -1
268995.6714 1504535.713 -1
268991.3611 1504537.965 -1
268992.4533 1504539.062 -1
269000.3851 1504455.991 0.5
268997.3706 1504482.578 0
268985.4058 1504476.042 2.5
268985.0218 1504555.727 -1
268968.5721 1504531.524 0
269013.5391 1504474.689 2.5
269010.2336 1504468.078 2
269013.6555 1504487.968 -1
269028.6251 1504466.81  1.6
```